# ¿Cómo se obtiene el texto de un enlace desde un div identificable por su nombre de clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scraping, beautifulsoup

Quiero anadir la informacion de cuantos Quotes de un articulo habia en el mio scraper que recupera los articulos que se recuperan a partir de una consulta en Google Scholar. Por ejemplo *"nlp explainability"*.

```
<a href="/scholar?cites=11880743428410665806&amp;as_sdt=2005&amp;sciodt=0,5&amp;hl=en">Cited by 48</a>
```

Hasta hoy intento obtenerlo con `[title=Cite]` pero, a diferencia de todos los demás, regresa vacío:

```
# this function for the extracting information of the tags
def get_tags(doc):
  paper_tag = doc.select('[data-lid]')
  cite_tag = doc.select('[title=Cite] + a')
  link_tag = doc.find_all('h3',{"class" : "gs_rt"})
  author_tag = doc.find_all("div", {"class": "gs_a"})

  return paper_tag,cite_tag,link_tag,author_tag

# this function for the getting inforamtion of the web page
def get_paperinfo(paper_url):

  #download the page
  response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

  # check successful response
  if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status code:', response.status_code)
    raise Exception('Failed to fetch web page ')

  #parse using beautiful soup
  paper_doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

  return paper_doc

url = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start={}&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=nlp+explainability&btnG=".format(1)

# function for the get content of each page
doc = get_paperinfo(url)

# function for the collecting tags
paper_tag,cite_tag,link_tag,author_tag = get_tags(doc)
```

Pienso que puedo utilisar `gs_fl`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Aqui esta el google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VKy6y0XKMA2qljzbxUekMeGlpRqJfI5s#scrollTo=VM01jvAaYR_y&uniqifier=1)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un selector que se base en el contenido del href del enlace:

```
doc.select('a[href*=\?cites\=]')
```

Así seleccionas los elementos `<a>` en cuyo atributo href esté la cadena `?cites=`